# ntfs partition missing when I installed ubuntu mate 14.4

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I had a Windows 8.1 installed on C partition of my laptop. I had 2 partitions, C and D. Recently I installed Ubuntu Mate 14.04. but I don't know how to find my files on D partition. Should I mount or something?

Any help would be appreciated...

I think the following information would help :

- `sudo fdisk -l`:

  ```
  Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes 255 heads, 63
  sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors Units =
  sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
  bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00087858

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
  /dev/sda2          501758  1465147391   732322817    5  Extended
  Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary. /dev/sda5     
  501760  1465147391   732322816   8e  Linux LVM

  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 745.8 GB, 745789194240 bytes 255
  heads, 63 sectors/track, 90670 cylinders, total 1456619520 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
  512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
  bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition
  table

  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4106 MB, 4106223616 bytes 255
  heads, 63 sectors/track, 499 cylinders, total 8019968 sectors Units =
  sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
  bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition
  table
  ```
- `df -h`:

  ```
  Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  684G  3.3G  646G   1% /
  none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  udev                         1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
  tmpfs                        388M  1.2M  386M   1% /run
  none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  none                         1.9G  292K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
  none                         100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
  /dev/sda1                    236M   36M  188M  17% /boot
  ```
- `sudo blkid`:

  ```
  /dev/sda1: UUID="56fa0875-40d6-4bbd-ae2a-f3e85341c44a" TYPE="ext2" 
  /dev/sda5: UUID="tQJELc-qT2m-xBFV-RfHJ-f7Vj-LIIn-KpAQ0Q" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="8f775671-a8d4-42b1-9ea4-90a7b7899c36" TYPE="ext4" 
  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="61daad35-5ff4-4417-b3b6-cbd0943e6a0f" TYPE="swap"
  ```
- `fdisk -l | grep NTFS`:

  ```
  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition         table
  Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got another physical disk, it looks like you've accidentally overwritten your Windows installation, including both `C:` and `D:` partitions.

If you have good backups, now is the time to use them.

If you do not have good backups, *shut down and stop using the disk immediately!* Your best hope for recovery is to use a tool like [PhotoRec,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which can recover files from badly damaged filesystems. (I've heard that some Windows tools can do a better job than PhotoRec on NTFS, but I don't remember the specifics or have pointers to these tools.) You'll need a second disk with sufficient capacity to hold your recovered files, and you'll need to boot to an emergency system to run PhotoRec (or whatever you use instead of it).

Comment: As a disk expert, could you have a look at the duplicate too?

Answer (score -1):

You need to mount /dev/sda5 to access D: drive.

Best way to do it temporarily is -

```
mkdir ~/myDdrive
sudo mount /dev/sda5 ~/myDdrive
```

To do it permanently, and for all users (and guest), make a /myDdrive (or whatever name you wish) directory in root

```
sudo mkdir /myDdrive
```

Then in your /etc/fstab file, add the mount line, that will executed every time, so you always have the drive mounted

```
/dev/sda5       /myDdrive      ntfs    rw
```

Comment: i did the temporarily way, but i got this :
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Comment: `/dev/sda5` is an LVM partition, not an NTFS partition.

Comment: @Nima, you are on a different volume group than the one on which your partition is,
This article might help
http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member.html

Comment: The type-0x8e ("Linux LVM") partition type indicates a ***Linux*** LVM. Windows cannot read that type of LVM, at least not natively, so Windows cannot be installed to it -- at least, not except in a virtualization tool like VirtualBox or QEMU that themselves run atop Linux. Nima's `fdisk` and `blkid` outputs indicate that there are *no NTFS or FAT partitions* on the disk.  Being "on a different volume group" has nothing to do with it; they've been ***wiped out!*** I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree, Arnav.